# CSS3 custom checkbox - cross-browser differences

Tags: forms, css, cross-browser

I've recently been working on some custom checkboxes for a while now and have found it to be a challenge. However, I'm so close to finishing them and had been testing a lot in Chrome which I managed to get them perfect.

I then checked in the other browsers and there were some distinct differences in how my after state was rendered. How do you fix those differences? is it even possible? Or do I just have to use an image?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mBWm3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-checkbox">
<br>
<br>
<input id="item21_0_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" data-hint=""    value="Conference" /><label for="item21_0_checkbox" id="item21_0_label" ><span id="item21_0_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Conference</span></label>
      <input id="item21_1_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Incentive campaign" /><label for="item21_1_checkbox" id="item21_1_label" ><span id="item21_1_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Incentive campaign</span></label>
      <input id="item21_2_checkbox"  name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Incentive travel" /><label for="item21_2_checkbox" id="item21_2_label" ><span id="item21_2_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Incentive travel</span></label>
      <input id="item21_3_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Awards dinner" /><label for="item21_3_checkbox" id="item21_3_label" ><span id="item21_3_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Awards dinner</span></label>
      <input id="item21_4_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Product launch" /><label for="item21_4_checkbox" id="item21_4_label" ><span id="item21_4_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Product launch</span></label>
      <input id="item21_5_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Hospitality" /><label for="item21_5_checkbox" id="item21_5_label" ><span id="item21_5_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Hospitality</span></label>
     <input id="item21_6_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Comms and marketing" /><label for="item21_6_checkbox" id="item21_6_label" ><span id="item21_6_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Comms and marketing</span></label>
      <input id="item21_7_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Reward &amp; Recoginition scheme" /><label for="item21_7_checkbox" id="item21_7_label" ><span id="item21_7_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Reward &amp; Recoginition scheme</span></label>
      <input id="item21_8_checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Design brief" /><label for="item21_8_checkbox" id="item21_8_label"><span id="item21_8_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Design brief</span></label>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
display: none!important;
}

/*------ 1st checkboxes  ----*/

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
width: 15px; height: 15px;
border: 1px solid #a5a5b1;
background: none;
border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.13);
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.13);
box-shadow:         inset 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.13);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:after {
content: '★';
position: absolute;
width: 15px; height: 15px;
top: -1px;
right: 10px;
font-size: 1.2em;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #ffc20e;
transition: all .5s;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
border: 1px solid #000000;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:after {
opacity: 0;
transform: scale(0);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:after {
opacity: 1;
transform: scale(1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label span:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label span:before {
box-shadow: none;
border-color: #bbb;
background-color: #ddd;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label span:after {
color: #999;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label span {
color: #aaa;
}

/* accessibility */
input[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label span:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label span:before {
 border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

If you click the boxes for their checked state and in different browsers you'll notice positioning is off and even the size of the star is slightly different...

EDIT: I know my example doesn't show them perfectly align to start off with - just interested in why they're positioned differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `line-height` corresponding to the element height for your `:after` elements used to display the star,

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:after,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:after {
  /* … */
  top: 0; /* modified */
  line-height: 13px;
}
```

With that, it looks OK to me in Firefox and Opera. http://jsfiddle.net/mBWm3/1/

Comment: Nice! This has given me a lot more consistency for the vertical position. Any way round the rendering of the star's size? Or is that just a difference in how the browsers render that element? IE, Safari display it much larger than Chrome, FF

Comment: That could be a problem of the font used to render the star character. (If the fonts in your font stack don’t include a glyph for that character, then the browser will try to find it in another font.) If you want more control over that, consider using an icon font that has a star glyph that looks exactly as you want. (Or maybe not use a text character at all, but a (background-)image – could be f.e. an SVG.)

Comment: I'm currently looking into an icon font that will hopefully solve this. Will report back soon!